# rstudio How to cancel alt+0

Tags: rstudio, shortcut

Instead of typing "<-", [Alt + -] is very useful.
However, sometimes you accidentally enter [Alt + 0] just to the left of [-].
Then my codes hide in Left Right Arrow like images.

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GG4D.jpg">
```

How can I goback and avoid the thousand of clicking?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GG4D.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may modify shortcuts in RStudio.

Go to Tools -> "Modify Keyboard Shortcuts..."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your comment become a hint.
Fold all : Alt + 0
Unfold all : Alt + Shift + O